Android Studio Java Check if Incoming Call is Forwarded
I am creating an android studio java app where i would like to check if the incoming call has been forwarded
Below is my manifest where i am declaring READ_PHONE_STATE permission and also declaring my receiver class where i am trying to implement the logic
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PhoneCallDivert"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <receiver android:name=".classes.CallReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


Below is my CallReceiver class
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (state != null && state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                boolean isForwarded = isCallForwarded(context, incomingNumber);
                if (isForwarded) {
                    Log.d("CallForwardedStatus", "Incoming call is forwarded");
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Call is forwarded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("CallForwardedStatus", "Incoming call is not forwarded");
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Call is not forwarded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Below is isCallForwarded method that i am trying to use to return true or false when the call comes in
private boolean isCallForwarded(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    boolean isForwarded = false;

    try {
        Bundle bundle = telephonyManager.getCallForwardingOption(CallForwardingOption.CF_UNCONDITIONAL, phoneNumber);
        if (bundle != null) {
            boolean isEnabled = bundle.getBoolean(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_IS_CF_ENABLED);
            String forwardedNumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_IS_CF_CURRENT_STATUS);

            isForwarded = isEnabled && !TextUtils.isEmpty(forwardedNumber);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e("CallForwarded", "SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return isForwarded;
}


But i am getting error Cannot resolve method 'getCallForwardingOption' in 'TelephonyManager'  is the method getCallForwardingOption available in telephonyManager or is there a different way i can be able to check if the call is forwarded
I have also tried below logic in my isCallForwarded method

 private boolean isCallForwarded(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        // Check if telephony service is available
        if (telephonyManager == null) {
            return false;
        }


        try {
            // Get the current forwarding state for the given number
            int forwardingState = telephonyManager.getCallForwardingReason(phoneNumber,
                    CallForwardingReason.TO_UNKNOWN);

            // Call is forwarded if the reason is not "REASON_UNKNOWN" (0)
            return forwardingState != CallForwardingReason.REASON_UNKNOWN;
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.w("CallForwarded", "SecurityException while checking call forwarding", e);
            return false;
        }
    }


But i get errors Cannot resolve method 'getCallForwardingReason' in 'TelephonyManager' and Cannot resolve symbol 'CallForwardingReason'

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager
This class does not contain getForwardingReason() method.

@NiceBooks i have checked in the link that you shared and the methods don't exist is there a method that i can use to check the call forwarded option
